# How to set host point to app.php file in Symfony2

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have a question need you guys help please

I have my apache server installed. And an Symfony2 application running. So my problem is, when deploy on server. How can i link to server host without include app.php in the URL.

Ex:
  When link to my app on Symfony, i have to enter a URL like this to access the app :

```
    localhost/app.php/
```

So how can i configure the server or somewhat i didn't know to access URL 'localhost/', it will auto link to same as 'localhost/app.php/'

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure URL rewriting in your virtual host or in the .htaccess file